# android soap service : how to get the property of the model

Tags: android, soap, wsdl, android-ksoap2, wsdl2java

i am developing a android application which use .net wsdl service. i can able to get result using soap object.

i tired to access the property but no use.

the problem is the property name are appended with random names .

please check the below image . instead for BidAccepted_BackingField i am getting _x003c_BidAccepted
some please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

:) Hope this can be helpful to you..

Try like this

```
    SoapEnvelope result = (SoapEnvelope) envelope.getResponse();
    Log.d("result : ", "" + result.toString());
    int elementCount = result.getPropertyCount();
    Log.d("count : ", ""+elementCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) 
    {
        Object property = result.getProperty(i);
        SoapObject obj= (SoapObject)property;               
        Log.d("OBject: ", ""+obj);

        String property_name=obj.getProperty(your_property_name).toString();

     }
```

Comment: yes your correct but i want to get the property by name. for example soapObject.getProperty("BidAccepted_BackingField"). my problem is when i debug i am getting _x003C_BidAccepted_x003E_k__BackingField  instead of BidAccepted_BackingField  in the property name.

Comment: String property_name=obj.getProperty("BidAccepted_BackingField").toString();

Comment: or if you get _x003c then it can be issue from Server I think'

Comment: Thn try String property_name=obj.getProperty("x003C_BidAccepted_x003E_k__BackingField").toString();